# Write in a text file

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write my A4:A8 data in a text file and this is my code :

```
Sub creer_TXT()


Close
  chemin = "C:\Users\bquinty\Desktop\"
  Open chemin & "txt.txt" For Output As #1
  Print #1, Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A4:A8")
  Close

Shell "C:\Users\bquinty\Desktop\txt.txt " & chemin & "txt.txt"
End Sub
```

Can someone explain me why it doesn't work please ?

Comment: Try: `Print #1, Join(Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A4:A8"),vbCrLF)`?

Comment: You need to better explain exactly what "it doesn't work" means. Do you get a runtime error? Which line blows up? Also your `Shell` command is provided with the path twice in the same string - it looks like your file might get generated fine and the `Shell` call blows up. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Also, your `Shell` command statement is very wrong.

Comment: It notice : wrong project or library at the line 5 : chemin = "C:\Users\bquinty\Desktop\"

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, line 5 is just assigning a string literal to what appears to be an undeclared local variable. You might want to stick `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and *declare* all variables you use, e.g. `Dim chemin As String`; also you'll want to get a free file number from VBA (`fn = FreeFile`, and then `Open chemin For Output As #fn`), instead of hard-coding a file number that may or may not be available to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as I test it.

First, you need to coerce the range/array of values from A4:A8 in to a string, which can be used with the `Print` statement. We do this by transposing the array, and then `Join` it with a `vbCrLf` delimiter (you could use a comma, pipe, tilde, tab, etc...)

Also, fix the `Shell` statement to open the file in Notepad.exe

```
Sub creer_TXT()
Dim chemin$
Dim textvals

  textvals = Worksheets(1).Range("A4:A8")
  textvals = Application.Transpose(textvals)
  textvals = Join(textvals, vbCrLf)
  '## Define the file path on one statement here, and we can use it again later without concatenating pieces of it
  chemin = "C:\Users\bquinty\Desktop\txt.txt"
  '## Open the file:
  Open chemin For Output As #1
  '## print the values to file
  Print #1, textvals
  Close

'## Open the file in notepad
Shell "notepad.exe " & chemin
End Sub
```